# anagram algorithm fault

Tags: java, algorithm, anagram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anagram algorithm in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692221/anagram-algorithm-in-java)

```
    public static boolean test(String a, String b) {
    a=a.toLowerCase();
    b=b.toLowerCase();
    boolean result = true ;
    boolean tmp1=false;

    if(a.length()==b.length()){
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
        tmp1=false;
        for(int k=0;k<b.length();k++){
            if(a.charAt(i)==b.charAt(k)){



                return true;
                }

        }
        if(tmp1==false){
            result=false;
            break;
        }
        if(i==a.length()-1)
            result=true;
        }
    }

    else {
        result=false;
        }



    return result;

}
```

I want to make a program to find anagram words.

The code works correctly when the input is

- word one is dsa
- second word is asd
- The output is anagram (correct result)

The code fails for the input

- first word is assa
- second word is asaa
- result is anagram (INCORRECT result)

What is my fault?

Comment: Is this week anagram homework week?

Comment: I would copy one of the many, many solutions already available. Or at least read them because there are much simpler and more efficient ways of doing this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I would not.  There is no learning in doing that.  He's written code, determined it does not work, and is seeking to learn why.  That is good.

Comment: @EricJ. He might learn that there are O(N ln N) solutions, with 6 lines of code, instead of O(N^2) but without some research the OP is unlikely to work that out for himself.

Comment: go back to the definition of anagram. both strings need to have the same number of occurences of every characters.

Comment: @durron597.. Add a worldwide before that. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm decides that a word is an anagram too soon - in fact, as soon as it can match the first letter of the first word to any letter of the second word:

```
if(a.charAt(i)==b.charAt(k)){
    return true;
}
```

The easiest algorithm for anagram detection in Java is as follows:

- Convert `a` and `b` [to arrays of characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) `charArrayA` and `charArrayB`
- [Sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char%5B%5D%29) `charArrayA` and `charArrayB`
- [Create strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D%29) `sortedA` and `sortedB` from sorted arrays
- Return `sortedA.equals(sortedB)`.

Comment: +1 In addition to this, if it were to get past that for loop it would inevitably return false since tmp1 is never changed.

Comment: @YusufBulak Strings are immutable, you cannot sort them.

Answer (score 1):

You let `i` run from 0 to `a.length()` and `k` from 0 to `b.length()`. So both loop variables start at the beginning of the respective string.

Furthermore in the inner loop you immediately return `true` for the whole function, if at any point any character in `b` matches a character in `a`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're going to use statements such as `return true` or `return false`, use them consistently (get rid of `boolean result`).

The problem with this algorithm is that as soon as it detects a pair of identical characters, it will return true. To fix this, consider sorting the two strings and testing the equality of all characters (hint: `Arrays.sort` and `String.toCharArray`).

Comment: I do not want make with char array